# Resize Image (jpg) in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

What is the best way to resize an image that is uploaded on a Blazor client page.  These are real simple images that I just wanted to have a consistent width and was hoping to use the System.Drawing, but that is not available in web assembly.  I was hoping to do it on the client, but is it best to send it to a Controller for processing?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: did you see system.drawing.common?

Comment: Resize them by css

Answer (score 2):

.NET 5 has an extension method to IBrowserFile called [RequestImageFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.browserfileextensions.requestimagefileasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0).  Per the documentation, it "Attempts to convert the current image file to a new one of the specified file type and maximum file dimensions."

Answer (score 0):

We use a package PhotoSauce.MagicScaler for all images uploaded from any blazor page.
https://photosauce.net/
I have no affiliation with this package / author etc.  Just recommend it because it works so well.

There are lots of params that you can set in the ProcessImageSettings for width, method of resizing etc.

```
var settings = new ProcessImageSettings { Height = 250 };
using var outStream = new FileStream(thumbNailPathAndFile, FileMode.Create);
MagicImageProcessor.ProcessImage(pathAndFile, outStream, settings);
```

Comment: It looks like this requires Windows so I doubt it would work in Blazor WebAssembly.